# SQL Unnest - how to use correctly?

Tags: sql, presto, trino, unnest

Say I have some data in a table, t.

```
id, arr
--, ---
1,  [1,2,3]
2,  [4,5,6]
```

SQL

```
SELECT AVG(n) FROM UNNEST(
    SELECT arr FROM t AS n) AS avg_arr
```

This returns the error, `'Mismatched input 'SELECT'. Expecting <expression>`.
What is the correct way to unnest an array and aggregate the unnested values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) is normally used with a `cross join` and will expand the array into relation (i.e. for every element of array an row will be introduced). To calculate average you will need to group values back:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (id, arr) AS (
    VALUES (1,  array[1,2,3]),
        (2,  array[4,5,6])
) 

--query
select id, avg(n)
from dataset
cross join unnest (arr) t(n)
group by id
```

Output:

| id | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.0 |
| 2 | 5.0 |

But you also can use [array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html). Depended on presto version either `array_average`:

```sql
select id, array_average(n)
from dataset
```

Or for older versions more cumbersome approach with manual aggregation via `reduce`:

```sql
select id, reduce(arr, 0.0, (s, x) -> s + x, s -> s) / cardinality(arr)
from dataset
```

Comment: In your first code block, what does `t(n)` do? It looks like it's referencing the table, t, and creating some index variable?

Comment: @jbuddy_13 `t(n)` is an alias for `unnest(arr)` result. Since `arr` is array it will be  expanded into a single column (`n`)